# C/C++ struct analogy in Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, struct

I have following code in C, and I have a very little knowledge in Java.

I want to know if there is any way I can create a structure shown in code below in Java. I guess we can do it using `class` in Java, but problem I'm facing in Java Classes is I could not declare people[10] i.e. an array of such a structure.

```
struct people{
float height;
float weight;
int age;
}people[10];

int main()       // this part of code is just to show how I can access all those elements of struct
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        people[i].height = rand()%7;
        people[i].weight = rand()%80;
        people[i].age = rand()%100;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf(" %f %f %d\n",people[i].height,people[i].weight,people[i].age);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not? Arrays of classes are perfectly OK in Java. Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: I mentioned _I have a very little knowledge in Java_ ,then why down votes?

Comment: @Ravi Because you are expected to have researched the problem before asking a question (this is in the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and your question is so basic that it's obvious you haven't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **C++** you can allocate objects statically ..

```
struct People
{
    // struct members are public by default
    float height;
    float weight;
    int age;
}
people[10]; // array of 10 objects

int main ()
{
    // fill some data
    people[0].age = 15;
    people[0].height = 1.60;
    people[0].weight = 65;

    return 0;
}
```

But in **Java**, you have to allocate objects dynamically, and creating the array will not allocate the objects, it will just allocate an array of references ..

```
package Example;

private class People
{
    // define members as public
    public float height;
    public float weight;
    public int age;
}

class Main
{
    public static main (String [] args)
    {
        // array of 10 references
        People [] p = new People [10];

        // allocate an object to be referenced by each reference in the array
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new People();
        }

        // fill some data
        people[0].age = 15;
        people[0].height = 1.60;
        people[0].weight = 65;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it:

```
public class Person {
    public float height;
    public float weight;
    public int age;

    private static Person[] people = new Person[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            people[i] = new Person();
            people[i].height = r.nextInt(7);
            people[i].weight = r.nextInt(80);
            people[i].age = r.nextInt(100);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            System.out.printf(" %f %f %d\n",
                people[i].height, people[i].weight, people[i].age);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You sir, for presenting a ditto version of my code, though it was just an example for me and answerers. I already did this 'Person[] people = new Person[10]' Only thing I was missing all time was 'people[i] = new Person();'... Thanks You and Khaled again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person{

private float height;
private float weight;
private int age;

public Person(float height, float weight, int age)
{
   this.height = height;
   this.weight = weight;
   this.age = age;
}

public float getHeight() { return height;}
...
...


public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int N=10;
 Person[] people = new Person[N];
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
   people[i] = new Person( ... , ... , ...)

}
```

}

Comment: OP has public members and no user defined constructor, so your example is quite different to theirs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use class. for creating people, u have to create objects of that class.

```
    people [] p  = new people[10];
    for(people person : p )
    {
         //each object is defined.
         p = new People(h,w,age);
    }

   class People{
        People(int h, int w, int a)
        {
            height=h; weight=w; age=a;
        }
    float height;
    float weight;
    int age;
    }
```